# Turing Machine Decidability

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, theory

Consider the language $L = \{\langle M_1,\ M_2 \rangle \mid \exists x : x \in L(M_1) \cap L(M_2)\}$. Show that $L$ is not decidable.

I'm attempting a proof by contradiction but I'm having trouble with the Turing machine part.

Comment: What is a turning machine? You make it rotate?

Comment: (Machines for [turning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning), for sure.)

Comment: Do you mean Turing machine?

Comment: Be nice, folks. Especially for a first post.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you chose $M_1 = \Sigma^*$. Could you find a $M_2$ that would fill the bill here?